# Can someone explain INSOMNIUM song lyrics for me

Tags: lyrics, metal

Can someone exaplain what this song's lyrics means: `Mortal Share

```
In their lofty chambers dwell
The sacred and divine
Resting in seraphic bliss
The timeless and sublime

Far above the mortal sphere
Dreaming without a care
Far above the weeping world
Sleeping amidst the light of stars

Too far away to hear our calls
Too far away to care at all

On the burnished thrones they sit
Might in their blazing eyes
Vault of heaven at their feet
Undying flames inside

Never shall decay or death
Touch on the blithe souls
Sorrowless the days of gods
Amidst the everblooming groves

But where do we lay our heads to rest?
Where do we shelter when the night falls?

For the part of man
Is to take the sombre path
Stumble in the dark
Stray amidst the dust and ash

Like forgotten ghosts
Drifting in the driving wind
Dashing towards the void
Whirling blindly through the night

Like water flung from the highest cliff
We fall,
Lunge,
Swirl,
Dissolve,
And fade away
Down into the unknown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal theme seems to be : **Celestial beings have a happy 'life', but mortals** (humans) **have a difficult life**.

Seraphic relates to [Seraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seraph) - a type of celestial being or angel. In this song we hear how they have nothing to worry about (*Dreaming without a care*), are strong and powerful (*Might in their blazing eyes...Undying flames inside*) and are never sad (*Sorrowless the days of gods*) and have really pretty things to look at (*Amidst the everblooming groves*).

We (humans) on the other hand can never feel safe and rested (*where do we lay our heads to rest? Where do we shelter when the night falls?*), Have no idea what we are doing (*Dashing towards the void; Whirling blindly through the night*) and our existence is ultimately meaningless (*fade away/Down into the unknown*).

Of course it could be a metaphor for some other groups of lucky and unlucky people.